# Can't boot into Linux mint 19.1 anymore

Tags: linux-mint, bios, thinkpad

Cant boot into linux mint 19.1 anymore
linux linux-mint grub2
So long story short, I was trying to create a startup script that will set up my environment for me and open all the applications I want.

I was testing the shell script while the laptop was on and finally got the script fully working.. opens a couple apps, opens some terminals and runs commands..

Now I placed the shell script into the startup folder for linux, and tried restarting my laptop.. then boom, linux doesnt load anymore..

What I get is a black screen that says GNU GRUB version 2.02... snooped around a bit and found out that when I type the ls command I get

(hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) error: failure reading sector 0x100800 from 'hd0'

Now I really dont care about this script, if I could somehow load system files and delete that script I have no problem.. any help is appreciated thanks

Idk if it matters, but it's a lenovo thinkpad t590

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can start by booting in live media and run an inspection of your hard drive to detect some badblocks.

In live media, identify your hard drive using: `sudo fdisk -l`

With sdX corresponding to the name of your hard drive, run badblock detection: `sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdX > /tmp/bad-blocks.txt`

Comment: ended up getting 8 bad blocks.. now what??

Comment: it means that it's probably not your hard drive that is dead. Where are located those 8 badblocks ?

Comment: Maybe you can try to make a [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)